# Adding highlight to ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, colors

My current terminal looks like this:

[image: terminal screenshot]

I know that I can change the font colour and the background colour, but I wanted to know if I can make the words be highlighted according to what they are (commands, parameters, ...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To highlight the grey@ubuntu:~$ section just edit ~/.bashrc

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

And then uncomment :

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

Then close and open terminal .

Answer (score -1):

In that terminal, go to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Colors and you can set it up there.

Comment: Thanks, but that only changes the background colour or the font colour...